# Playing with Java Compilation

Tags: java, sdk, runtime

I have developed an SDK in Java for which I also have a runtime. I want to restrict development using my runtime jars. My SDK is node-locked but I dont want to keep runtime node-locked so that my clients are free for developing applications using my SDK and sell and run at their clients using runtime. I havent written my own compiler and I dont want to. Can anybody suggest a trick to achieve this.

Comment: This is a social not a technical problem.

Comment: Even if you were able to achieve this, how do you propose to prevent your clients from writing/distributing adapters which simply re-direct calls to your API?

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand this correctly: you want to find a way to allow free distribution of the JARs needed to run the programs developed with the SDK, but want to prevent people from using those runtime JARs to develop new apps?

If so, and if the SDK does not offer essential functionality that supports development but is not needed at runtime, then I think the best way is to make the runtime not something that is distributed as an independant JAR. Instead, have the SDK provide a build functionality that bundles the runtime and the application, and inserts some code into the runtime libraries that checks for the presence of that particular application and refuses to run otherwise.

Comment: SDK does offer entire functionality that runtime offers. But my SDK is priced and I want vendors to buy it from me and thats why it is node locked. But using that SDK the clients of the vendor cant run the app they bought from vendor. So they need my runtime which is free. but then the problem is the clients of my vendor will start developing new apps on that runtime just by adding those jars in references. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Bottom line is I want to stop compilation of user code when my runtime jars are in reference and allow the application to run which is developed using my SDK and using runtime jars to run.